# Let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable, prove the following

Tags: statistics

Let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable, prove:

$P(Z > z) \leq \frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}}{2}$

How do I approach this question? Do I assume the moment generating function (in Chernoff Bounds) is $e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$? Does it even have anything to do with moment generating function or I can just simply use something like Markov's inequality or Chebyshev's inequality to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Chernoff bound. Since the mgf of standard normal random variable is $e^{t^2/2}$, we have

$$\begin{split}P(Z>z)&\le \frac{\mathbb E(e^{tZ})}{e^{tz}},\forall t\ge0\\
&=\frac{e^{\frac 12 t^2}}{e^{tz}}\\
&=e^{\frac 12 t^2-tz}\\
&=e^{\frac 12 (t^2-2tz+z^2)-\frac 12 z^2}\\
&=e^{\frac 12(t-z)^2-\frac 12z^2}\end{split}$$

Letting $t=z$, we get the lower bound:

$$P(Z>z)\le e^{-\frac 12z^2}$$

This doesn't have the factor of $1/2$ though, so maybe you require a stronger type of bound.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x) = 1 - \Phi(x) - e^{-x^2/2}/2$, where $\Phi(x)$ is the standard normal cdf. Then
$$
f'(x) = e^{-x^2/2} \left(-\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} +\frac{x}2 \right),
$$
so $f$ decreases for $x< \sqrt{2/\pi}$ and increases for $x>\sqrt{2/\pi}$. Since $f(0) = f(+\infty) = 0$, it follows that $f(x) <0$ for $x>0$.

---

For $x>\sqrt{2/\pi}$, one can also use the standard estimate $1-\Phi(x) < \phi(x)/x$, which is even better.